# Logstash codec and character encoding problem

Tags: python, logstash, kibana, logstash-configuration

I send logs from a desktop python application (Python 3.6) to Logstash (7.5.0), when I want to log an error message for example with the text ">>>>>>>> ERROR <<<<<<<", in the logstash log file I see the following entry:

> [2020-01-22T13:25:02,330][WARN ][logstash.codecs.line     ][main] Received an event that has a different character encoding than you configured. {:text=>"\u0000\u0000\u0000MainThreadq\u001AX\v\u0000\u0000\u0000processNameq\eX\v\u0000\u0000\u0000MainProcessq\u001CX\a\u0000\u0000\u0000processq\u001DM\u001D\xEDu.\u0000\u0000\u0002\u001D}q\u0000(X\u0004\u0000\u0000\u0000nameq\u0001X\b\u0000\u0000\u0000__main__q\u0002X\u0003\u0000\u0000\u0000msgq\u0003X\u0018\u0000\u0000\u0000>>>>>>>> ERROR <<<<<<"UTF-8"}

And in Kibana, when I query the received messages, I see that some (in this case, 6) individual messages have been sent to Logstash per each log message that I sent (in this case, ">>>>>>>> ERROR <<<<<<<") as follows:

```
{
        "_index" : "logstash-2020.01.23",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "lNXhz28BzTlrr0WBIjwA",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "host" : "localhost",
          "port" : 50197,
          "message" : """\u0000\u0000\u0000stack_infoq\u0011NX\u0006\u0000\u0000\u0000linenoq\u0012K'X\b\u0000\u0000\u0000funcNameq\u0013X\b\u0000\u0000\u0000<module>q\u0014X\a\u0000\u0000\u0000createdq\u0015GA\u05CA;vϯWX\u0005\u0000\u0000\u0000msecsq\u0016G@n\xA2u\xEC\u0000\u0000\u0000X\u000F\u0000\u0000\u0000relativeCreatedq\u0017G@E\u001DM\xD0\u0000\u0000\u0000X\u0006\u0000\u0000\u0000threadq\u0018L4437804480L""",
          "@version" : "1",
          "@timestamp" : "2020-01-23T00:50:35.362Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "logstash-2020.01.23",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "k9Xhz28BzTlrr0WBITyc",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "host" : "localhost",
          "port" : 50197,
          "message" : """threadNameqX""",
          "@version" : "1",
          "@timestamp" : "2020-01-23T00:50:35.362Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "logstash-2020.01.23",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "kdXhz28BzTlrr0WBITyc",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "host" : "localhost",
          "port" : 50197,
          "message" : """MainThreadqXprocessNameqXMainProcessqXprocessqMC0u.""",
          "@version" : "1",
          "@timestamp" : "2020-01-23T00:50:35.369Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "logstash-2020.01.23",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "ktXhz28BzTlrr0WBITyc",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "host" : "localhost",
          "port" : 50197,
          "message" : "X",
          "@version" : "1",
          "@timestamp" : "2020-01-23T00:50:35.362Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "logstash-2020.01.23",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "j9Xhz28BzTlrr0WBITyc",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "host" : "localhost",
          "port" : 50197,
          "message" : """XfilenameqXtest2.pyqXmoduleq
Xtest2qXexc_infoqNXexc_textqNX""",
          "@version" : "1",
          "@timestamp" : "2020-01-23T00:50:35.345Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "logstash-2020.01.23",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "kNXhz28BzTlrr0WBITyc",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "host" : "localhost",
          "port" : 50197,
          "message" : """}q(XnameqX__main__qXmsgqX>>>>>>>> ERROR <<<<<<<qXargsqNX   levelnameqXERRORqXlevelnoqK2Xpathnameq  X1/Users/e0h014b/PycharmProjects/logstash2/test2.pyq""",
          "@version" : "1",
          "@timestamp" : "2020-01-23T00:50:35.331Z"
        }
      }
```

The logstash config file which I’m using is as the following:

```
input {
    tcp {
        port => 5959
        codec => plain {
                charset => "UTF-8"
        }
     }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
  }
}
```

What should I do to have a normal format of logging in Logstash? Which codec and character encoding are proper in this application?

Thanks,
Elahe

Comment: did it work with the default codec as I suggested?

Comment: I tried default codec by not mentioning the codec in the config file and it didn't have any change. I didn't see anything related to default codec in apt-get_install_skill, could you please mention where you mentioned that point?

Answer (score 0):

If your log-messages just contain simple lines, you should go with the default codec, namely **line**.

I would always start with the default codec, test, verify the indexed data and then do some fine-tuning/changes to the codec if necessary.

Refer to this [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.5/codec-plugins.html) about all available codecs.

I hope I could help you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I already tried the line, multiline, JSON, plain codecs, they didn't work. JSON and multiline stick log messages together and also line and plain codecs have the same result as described above.

Comment: Do you mean I should test all the codecs that seem they are for different or special log message types?

Comment: Maybe the reason is not the logstash codec and character encoding problem and it has another reason.